# Wal-e : " pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived"

Tags: postgresql, backup, aws, write-ahead-logging

I've been trying to use wal-e to take incremental backup of my postgresql database by following [this](https://edwardsamuel.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/set-up-scheduled-postgresql-backup-to-aws-s3-using-wal-e/) blog. I've a database on my postgresql and using an AWS S3 bucket. while I'm using the following command

`sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-push /var/lib/postgresql/10/main`

it shows this [image: output]

Any help on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there anything uploaded to the bucket?

Comment: yes, a base backup from another pc, following the same precedures. do they conflict?

Comment: No, I mean from this try.  I wouldn't expect them to conflict in any case, unless maybe if they are taken from the exact same point.  Apparently something is wrong around uploading to S3.

Comment: no from this try, there's nothing uploaded. :(

Comment: Now that's what you have to debug: is uploading anything by hand (via the AWS CLI, for example) working from this machine?

Comment: Yes, I can upload anything by hand

Comment: Do you see anything in the Postgres logs that might refer to this?  Based on `pg_start_backup` it should be easy to find.